# how to remove scrollbar using inline css. I want to do it on just javascript as i created this in just vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-selectors

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzeS3.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAQVA.png)

Here is my code and here is the output. I want to remove the scrollbar using just vanilla javascript.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to use your code because you provided an image instead of something that can be copy-pasted. But here's your answer:

You **can** disable scrollbars with inline CSS for **FireFox** and for **IE + Edge**.

You **can't** disable Chrome, Safari, or Opera scrollbars with inline CSS. You must use a `<style>` tag.

```html
<!-- Disabling scrollbars for Internet Explorer, Edge, and Firefox -->
<html style="margin: 0; padding: 0; -ms-overflow-style: none; scrollbar-width: none">
    <body style="height: 200vh">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background: green"></div>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background: orange"></div>
    </body>
</html>

<style>
    /* Disabling scrollbars for Chrome, Opera, and Safari */
    body::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```